# TouchPad Multitouch is not working on 14.04

Tags: touchpad

```
navidda@MyLeno:~$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have a lenovo z511 and the touchpad seems to be detected as mouse. I had the same problem on 13.10 :-/

Answer (score 0):

I did this via command line and it fixed my touchpad in 14.04 for horizontal scrolling with multitouch, after reboot:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad horiz-scroll-enabled "true"
```

Comment: still not working