# Touchpad not detected

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, multi-touch, synaptics, system-settings

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in the new Lenovo Z510 Ideapad laptop. To check if my Touchpad is detected I typed the command

> xinput list

and this is my output:

[image: img]

I tried everything mentioned in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196250/dell-inspiron-n5110-touchpad-not-detected), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449975/touchpad-multitouch-is-not-working-on-14-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199581/my-toshiba-touchpad-not-working/199592#199592). i have made touchpad-enabled to true. 
But still the same problem persists. 
and this is how my mouse & touch pad setting looks like:

[image: img]

Help.

Comment: Please post the output of `xinput --list-props 13`

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Comment: I haven't had this problem. I installed touchegg using [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451386/how-to-achieve-multi-touch-gestures-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev
```

reboot

```
wget https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/+attachment/3941591/+files/psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz
dkms ldtarball psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz
dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-x551c
rmmod psmouse
modprobe psmouse
```