# Lenovo ThinkPad E550 Touchpad Not Working After Forced Shutdown (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad

I am having issues with my touchpad in Ubuntu 14.04. I was running a simulation which caused my computer to slow down too much to even be able to abort the code, so I was forced to use the power button to shutdown my laptop. Ubuntu had asked me to restart my computer to finish updating, but I decided to restart later (I feel like this may be related, but I really don't know). Ever since I started up my computer after this event, I have been unable to use my trackpad. My left, middle, and right mouse buttons work, but the trackpad does not register any movement (it also cannot zoom, scroll, etc.) When I use xinput in the terminal, it still reads "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad" (other things I've seen apparently recognize the touchpad as a PS/2 generic mouse, but that is not the case for me). I've been searching around the internet and trying a slew of different proposed solutions, but none of them have helped at all.  Does anyone know how I might be able to fix this? Thank you!

Edit: I'm dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows, and on Windows the touchpad works perfectly fine. There has been no physical damage done to my touchpad and the laptop is only a couple months old.

Comment: There is something called recovery or similar run that (found in the boot loader)

Comment: Under advanced options in the boot loader, there's the version of the kernel (Recovery Mode). Is this what you were talking about? If so, there are a lot of options to choose from; what do I do once I get there?

Answer (score 0):

After much struggling, I found a solution that worked for me, and will hopefully work for others who run into a similar issue. Following the instructions [here](http://linuxg.net/ubuntu-13-04-touchpad-option-does-not-exist-error-fix/), I removed all my alps folders in /usr/src/ and finished the instructions to no avail (I did install everything like they said and it's still in /usr/src/, so it may've helped). After deleting the folders, neither my trackpad nor the pointing stick nub on my keyboard would work (an external USB mouse still worked). I then ran `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469746/touchpad-not-detected). I rebooted my computer, and both my touchpad and the pointing stick nub work again! I didn't even need to do anything else described in the second link. I hope that someone, somewhere may find this helpful one day!